# Is Hibernate 3.x compatible with Log4j2?

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

I have an application which uses **Hibernate 3** and **log4j1.x**.
I am trying to migrate it to **log4j2**.
As soon as the `log4j 1.x` dependencies are removed from the application, I am seeing:
`runtime Error - NoClassDefFoundError for Hibernate classes`

Once I add back `log4j1.x` the errors are gone and everything works perfectly fine.

Please note that I am not using any references to `log4j1.x` in my application. It is included just to make Hibernate happy.

Please let me know if Hibernate 3 is not compatible with Log4j2.x.
Also is there a workaround other than adding log4j1.x as a dependency ?

Comment: Maybe you should searche aout the compatibility of Log4j 1 & 2.

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144790/how-to-configure-hibernate-logging-using-log4j2-xml) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to migrate to Hibernate 4 or better yet 5, as Hibernate 3 is very old and no longer supported, meaning there are no more security updates for example.

If you use Maven it should automagically figure out your dependencies for you btw. But yes, Hibernate 3 most likely requires Log4J1 or commons-logging internally. It's too old to know about Log4J2. MAYBE having SLF4J with a Log4J1 adapter will be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.